# Find the convenient $n$ which make $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1$ be true.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My question is:

> For which $n$ respect to $\alpha$ (where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$), the following inequality is true? 
>   $$\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; ?$$
>   or equivalently $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}}\geq \; \pi^n\;\;;\;n\geq\; ?$

To answer this question, at first I supposed that $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$. So I arrive at the following

If $\alpha=1$ then $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; 9$;

If $\alpha=2$ then $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; 11$;

If $\alpha=3$ then $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; 14$;

If $\alpha=4$ then $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; 16$;

If $\alpha=5$ then $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; 18$;

If $\alpha=6$ then $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; 20$;

If $\alpha=7$ then $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; 21$;

If $\alpha=8$ then $\frac{n!}{n^{\alpha}\; \pi^n}\geq 1\;\;;\;n\geq\; 23$;

So I could not guess any closed form for $n$ which $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ case, and I think this method does not work even for integer case. Also I could not find any thing about $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.  Thanks for any useful help.

Comment: Improved and much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be, you could consider that you look for  $n$ such that
$$\frac{\log \left(\pi ^{-n}\, n!\right)}{\log (n)}=\alpha$$ and notice that, very quickly, the lhs is almost a straight line.

This seems to be interesting for Newton method. The problem being the starting guess, using your values for $\alpha=6$ and $\alpha=8$, let me propose the simple
$$n_0=17+\frac 32 \alpha$$

Trying for $\alpha=123$, the iterates would be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & n_k \\
 0 & 201.500 \\
 1 & 204.891 \\
 2 & 204.889
\end{array}
\right)$$

Still playing now for $\alpha=1234$, the iterates would be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & n_k \\
 0 & 1868.00 \\
 1 & 1731.55 \\
 2 & 1731.36
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, we could work a better guess $n_0$ but this seems to work.

**Edit**

Working backward, it seems that a better estimate could be
$$n_0=\frac{417}{98}+\frac{232 }{93}\alpha ^{39/80}+\frac{169 }{106}\alpha ^{39/40}$$
Using $\lceil n_0 \rceil$ for $\alpha=1,2,\cdots,8$ (cases you worked), this would give for $n_0$ the sequence $\{9,11,14,16,18,20,22,24\}$ which does not seem to be too bad.

Concerning the worked cases : for $\alpha=123$, this would give $\lceil n_0 \rceil=205$ and, for $\alpha=1234$, this would give $\lceil n_0 \rceil=1732$; these happen to be the solutions.

For $\alpha=12345$, this would give $\lceil n_0 \rceil=15803$ while the exact solution would be $15862$.

Using this totally empirical formula for $n_0$, I suppose that one  Newton iteration would give the result.

Concerning the  derivative (required by Newton method), its formal expression is quite complex and I would suggest to compute it using finite differences that it to say to use
$$\frac d {dn} \left(\frac{\log \left(\pi ^{-n}\, n!\right)}{\log (n)}\right)=\frac 12\left(\frac{\log \left(\pi ^{-n-1}\, (n+1)!\right)}{\log (n+1)}-\frac{\log \left(\pi ^{-n+1}\, (n-1)!\right)}{\log (n-1)}\right)$$ or, even simpler, to approximate it using
$$\frac d {dn} \left(\frac{\log \left(\pi ^{-n}\, n!\right)}{\log (n)}\right) \approx 1-\frac{\log(\pi e)}{\log(n)}+\frac{\log(\pi e)}{\log^2(n)}$$

Comment: Stirling's approximation says that $\alpha/n \approx 1-(1+\ln \pi)/\ln n$, which might help make a better initial guess.

Comment: @eyeballfrog. I did think about it hoping to use Lambert function but I did not find anything. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici, Firstly, thanks for your answer. then would you explain more about your answer. For example why you consider that $n_0$? and does your answer work just for integer $\alpha$ or not? Also we should look for $n$ which $\frac{\log \left(\pi ^{-n}\, n!\right)}{\log (n)}\geq\alpha$. finally $n$ must be greater than what respect to $\alpha$. does there exist any closed form for that? thanks

Comment: @soodehMehboodi. You are welcome ! To use Newton method, you need a guess; this is $n_0$ and I just used your numbers just to have the order of magnitude. I hope that you see how fast it does converge. I made the problem continuous and used algebra. About closed form, stop dreaming about it. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici, your Edit is great, but how did you guess the recently $n_0$? Also, did you change your mind about closed forms?

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici, By the way, in your answer, you supposed $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$. How about others (i.e.,  $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$)? Do you have any idea? thanks.

Comment: @soodehMehboodi. I did not changed my mind about closed form. For the "improved" $n_0$, as I wrote, I worked backward : for a given $n$, I compute $\alpha$ and then a quick and dirty regression work (totally empirical model) leads to that. Since I used algebra, I don't have any problem as long as $\alpha$ is a real number.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici,, thanks a lot.